# Call intent to make a call with put extra to select a phone number in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a way a user can contact a friend via sms, email and a phone call. I have completed the email and SMS part. I have figured out how to use createChooser to select how a message will be sent using either email or text message, this is achieved by clicking on a button, the following code is how I do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                i.setType("text/plain");

                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{""});

                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out my awesome score!");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "I am playing this awesome game called Tap the Button, and I just scored the incredible highscore of " +s+ " Taps!!\n\nCan you beat it!?");
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(Fail.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

My aim is to have a button that opens a form like this does where the user can select a phone number from the phones phone book.

The above email and text code allows me to choose which way to send the message from the available ways to do it on this phone, if I select email it creates the form using the putExtra. I want one put extras to click on and select a phone number from the phones address book. Here is my latest attempt at this:

```
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                    callIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    callIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, new String[]{""});

                    try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(callIntent, "CAlling..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(Fail.this, "There are no call clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

When I run the code it catches an exception, saying there is no call client. I have this permission in my android manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
```

I would appreciate any advice on this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling is acheived by using the tel: scheme, not using an extra:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
```

Comment: When the use presses the call button within the application, I don't want them to have to type in a number, I want them to type in a contact name, as they type it in, options appear, this is how it happens with the email and sms code, I was hoping to achieve the same. If you say it is different, does this mean that the user needs to know a number  in order to do this?

Thanks

Comment: to call someone, you need their phone number, yes. but to send an SMS to, so I don't see why it would be different from one case to another. Else, if you want to summon the call application, use the ACTION_DIAL

Comment: Because in the code I posted for the email and sms it opens up a selection of ways to send a message, I select any of them and the form appears on screen, which takes a number for a text, email address for an email etc.. when I click in the number/email field, the phone book is automatically opened. If I type r, it starts with the r's, I wanted the same thing with the phone calling, so it opened up a field to input a number, you tap in there, say start to type a name, it  displays your contacts, you select a name and then press enter and it opens the call intent.

Comment: what you are doing is that you are invoking an existing application. You need to find the intent that calls the application that does what you want. most likely, it can be ACTION_DIAL, or `Intent pickcontact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI); ` something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I can get this to work but only with hard coding a phone number, I tried using pickcontact but it tells me this is deprecated, it also didn't work, is this the only way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: action_dial should take you to the 'native' dialer, and this should let the user input a phone number or select a contact as they would normally do, i think

Comment: Yes for some reason it wouldn't work I went back to the drawing board and it works! Now I just need to make the app return to the title screen upon the call ending! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine .....

```
 public class Call_Sms_Email_IntentActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {
    private static final String NUMBER = "9409668178";
    Button call, sms, email;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
    sms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sms_btn);
    email = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_btn);

    call.setOnClickListener(this);
    sms.setOnClickListener(this);
    email.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == call) {
        // startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" +
        // mEditText_number.getText())));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"
                + Call_Sms_Email_IntentActivity.NUMBER));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (v == sms) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        /** creates an sms uri */
        Uri data = Uri.parse("sms:");
        intent.setData(data);

        /*
         * Put the default text intent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
         * intent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
         */
        /**
         * Initiates the SMS compose screen, because the activity contain
         * ACTION_VIEW and sms uri
         */
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (v == email) {

         Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

         String aEmailList[] = { "user@fakehost.com"};
         String aEmailCCList[] = {
         "user3@fakehost.com","user4@fakehost.com"};
         String aEmailBCCList[] = { "user5@fakehost.com" };

         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, aEmailBCCList);
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My message body.");

         emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
         "Send email..."));
}}}
```